# Turn php variables to functions

Tags: php

I've tried many times to turn Variables into Functions

```php
<?php
$echo = "Hello world!";
function echoIt() {
  echo $echo;
}

echoIt();
?>
```

But return this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: echo

Comment: This code will not produce that error. This code will give you an "Undefined variable" warning. Also, what do you mean by turning variables to functions? Seems like all you're trying to do is to pass an argument to the function.

Comment: It looks like you want to feed a function with an argument, like [so](https://3v4l.org/Ju7Wa). If you want to assign a function to a variable (_turn Variables into Functions_) then have a look at [anomymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). Also, suggested reading variable [scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the actual error message. If you were really asking about a parse error the question would be off-topic anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work because `$echo` is not in the [function scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

You don't normally want to do that anyway. It tends to make your code impossible to understand because variables pop up from nowhere and you never know where they get created or modified. Instead, you want to pass each function the values it needs, e.g.:

```
<?php

function echoIt(string $text): void
{
    echo $text;
}

$echo = "Hello world!";
echoIt($echo);
```

Please note I've also removed the trailing `?>` tag. It isn't required and it can often cause problems when trailing whitespace characters slip.

Comment: _"it isn't required"_ ... [more precisely](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/): _"The closing `?>` tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP."_

Comment: @berend While totally recommended, PSR-12 is a third-party _coding style_, not really anything enforced by PHP as syntax or runtime.